# Code not working for Pivot Data Set having Rows>65536

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, pivot-table

My purpose is to create a Pivot Table and further a Pivot Chart out of the Dump data (A1:AE170000) I have. I've attached my code below, which works perfectly fine if I reduce my data to around 60-65k rows, but not otherwise.

It throws Runtime error 13 : Type Mismatch at the line I am setting up my Pivot Cache (PTCache).

```
Private Sub OptionButton3_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Activate

    Dim PTCache As PivotCache
    Dim PT As PivotTable
    'Setting range as my entire data set
    Dim PTRange As Range
    Set PTRange = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))
    'Adding a new worksheet for Pivot Table and Chart
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets.Add
    ws.Name = "All"
    PTRange.Select
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("All").Activate
    'Runtime error 13:Type Mismatch at this line while setting PTCache
    Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, PTRange)
    Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add(PTCache, Range("A1"), "All")
    With PT
        .PivotFields("Name").Orientation = xlPageField
        .PivotFields("Rate").Orientation = xlDataField
        .PivotFields("Date").Orientation = xlRowField
    End With
    PT.PivotSelect ("")

    Charts.Add
    ActiveChart.Location where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=PT.Parent.Name
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.Parent.Top = Range("I7").Top
    ActiveChart.Parent.Left = Range("I7").Left

    Range("A2").Select
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Which excel are you using

Comment: How can you select PTRange from the Data worksheet when the new worksheet you just added is active?

Comment: I am using Excel 2007. And I Activated the new worksheet after setting and selecting PTRange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [PivotCaches.Create Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839430.aspx) (my emphasis):

> *<blah><blah>* ... When passing as a range, it is recommended to either use a string to specify the workbook, worksheet, and cell range, or set up a named range and pass the name as a string. **Passing a Range object may cause "type mismatch" errors unexpectedly**.

Just set up a string var to the external address of the Data worksheet's [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) radiating out from A1 and use that.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub OptionButton3_Click()
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim PT As PivotTable, PTCache As PivotCache
    Dim PTRange As Range, ws As Worksheet, strRNG As String

    strRNG = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Address(external:=True)

    With Worksheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        .Name = "All"
        Set PTCache = .Parent.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, strRNG)
        Set PT = .PivotTables.Add(PTCache, .Range("A1"), "All")
        With PT
            .PivotFields("Name").Orientation = xlPageField
            .PivotFields("Rate").Orientation = xlDataField
            .PivotFields("Date").Orientation = xlRowField
        End With
        PT.PivotSelect ("")
    End With

    'all the chart stuff here

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: By [Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621.aspx) I guess you mean discontiguous columns. Build the union and try it with just the [Range.Address External:=True](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) as a string. If that doesn't work, post some data with the code into a new question. This was a pretty good question; don't want it to become a [Russian Doll Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625).